# Uploading Files in Node

Tags: node.js, express

I'm allowing users to upload files and would like to know if it is possible to only allow the user who uploaded their files access to it.

Currently I am just uploading these to a static folder (Public).

Comment: This question is exceptionally broad and is actually asking "How do I implement authentication to limit access to certain files." I'm not saying it's a bad question as you may already have auth implemented, but the action of protecting a static file from being sent to an unauthorized user should be the same as one protecting a section of your website from being accessed by an unauthorized user.

Comment: On that note, do you have any pre-existing authentication code and strategies implemented?

Comment: I have an extensive authentication process. I even require them to register and have their account activated prior to using the application.

Comment: Well, there you go. Protect the route which handles serving the file and only allow authenticated users who match the file's owner. I don't see how this is any different from authentication for viewing a static page.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a route to render the file (this will decrease performance)
Save the file as : filename.extension.userid in a non public folder for example a directory named upload.

Put a route to catch the request on the directory upload :

```
app.get("/upload/:filename", function(req, res){
   var  fname = req.params.filename;
   var  userid = req.user.id; // RETRIEVE AUTHENTICATED USER ID

   var fullname = fname+"."+userid;
   fs.readFile(__dirname+"/../public/upload/"+fullname, 'base64', function(err, data){
      if(err || !data) return res.status(404);
       res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'+fname+'"');
       res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); // example for pdf
       return res.end(data, 'base64');
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a reason why you were suggesting using another route to handle the upload. I was able to post to the same route. All that I needed to do was include the path and set it accordingly.

```js
var folder = newPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', './uploads')
var newPath = folder + '/' + callback.fileName;

fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {

  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    //Do stuff
  }
});
```

After the file was uploaded I was then able to complete my task.

Comment: This answer seems relatively far from what you were asking. All this code does is upload the file to a slightly different directory. It does nothing to protect the file, which is what your question was implying ("only allow the user who uploaded their files access to it.") As such, I might recommend trying to be more clear with your questions as the SO community can't help when the information we're given is ambiguous and lacks information.